# How to use SASS in Ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, sass, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to use SASS in my project. I open this link and follow all command. I create a project and setup SASS.
http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/working-with-sass/

I got this directory structure

```
   scss
     |
     |—>ionic.app.scss
   www
     |
     |->css
          |
          |——>ionic.app.css
```

In **index.html** file I imported **ionic.app.css** in `style` tag. So whatever I change in **ionic.app.scss** file it comes **ionic.app.css** file and reflect in view .

If I add some element in index.html, for example I added Paragraph tag in `<ion-content>`:

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <p id=“addp”>Testparagraph</p>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

and added this

```
#addp{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

in **ionic.app.scss**, it added in **ionic.app.css** and reflect In view.

Now what I try to do. I want to add own file **“application.scss”**  in sass folder which should create another file **“application.css”**  in css folder. So whatever I code in  “application.scss” it come in  “application.css” file and it reflect in view. I import **“application.css”** in **index.html** file.

Where I write this code so I to generate this file and watch the my **“application.scss”**  file.

When I run ionic server and I change anything in **“ionic.app.scss”** file it reflect on view same time. I need to do same with **“application.scss”**. If I change **“application.scss”** it will reflect on my view .

This my **gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
    .on('log', function(data) {
      gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
    });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
    );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your `application.scss` should have only the variables used by your other custom .scss files, The idea being, you Change one value and it will change the it all the .scss files.

and your `gulp` process will compile all your files to a minified css file.

Have a look at, [ionic scss folder](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/tree/master/scss) and their [variables file](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss)

and the variables used in `_variables.scss` is same as `ionic.app.scss`. you can have all the variables defined in `_variables.scss` in `ionic.app.scss`.

Hope u have an idea on how Ionic does it, so you could follow the same structure

Comment: you didnot get my question I need to add another file .If I am not interested to work with _variables.scss or ionic.app.scss file.I want to add this application.scss in my sass folder ,which should geneate another css file.That css file I will import on index.html

Comment: But when I add application.scss in sass folder gulp process not watch my file.Not reflect on html view

Comment: you have to change the line `gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')` to `gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')`, to pick any .scss file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change it in gulp but i opened another terminal and i used sass --watch function(ex: **sass --watch scss/application.scss:www/css/application.css**), whenever if your doing changes in application.scss it will automatically update in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Change `gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')` to `gulp.src(paths.sass)`.

This will automatically build all .scss files in that folder or any subfolder into a corresponding .css file in /www/css/. Your current Gulp file is building ionic.app.css *and* an ionic.app.min.css, where the second one is minified for the smallest possible file size. It will do the same for any other files. You'll be able to just write **/scss/application.scss** and have it taken care of.

If you want to save yourself a lot of trouble, you can use this alternative to build all your SCSS files into a single build.css and build.min.css file.

```
gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src(paths.sass)
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(concat('build.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});
```